# How to add text from another class to a JMessage box?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, runtime-error

Not sure how to use a string I made in another class as the body text for a JMessage box I made. Any other suggestions are welcome. FYI what I am trying to do is get a message box with an output that is defined in another class to display on button press, the box will display, but not when I set it's body to the string from the other class. I also am determining this value when the button is pressed in another class and pushing the values FROM my JFrame class to my class that is handling all of my calculation stuff. Here's the code:

JFrame class code:

```
package clock;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class displayFrame extends JPanel{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static int hrsIn;
public static int daysIn;
public static int monthsIn;
public static int yearsIn;
public static int timeAdd;
public static JButton enter;
public static JLabel dayLabel, hourLabel, monthLabel, yearLabel, timeAdded1, newTime;
public static JTextField dayField, hourField, monthField, yearField, timeAdded;
public static JFrame frame;
public static JPanel newTimePanel;

public displayFrame()
{
    super(new BorderLayout());

    enter = new JButton("Okay");

    dayField = new JTextField(20);
    hourField = new JTextField(20);
    monthField = new JTextField(20);
    yearField = new JTextField(20);
    timeAdded = new JTextField(20);


    hourLabel = new JLabel("Hour: ", JLabel.CENTER);
    dayLabel = new JLabel("Day: ", JLabel.CENTER);
    monthLabel = new JLabel("Month: ", JLabel.CENTER);
    yearLabel = new JLabel("Year: ", JLabel.CENTER);
    timeAdded1 = new JLabel("Added: ", JLabel.CENTER);
    newTime = new JLabel(basic.output, JLabel.CENTER);

    JPanel button = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    button.add(enter);

    JPanel fieldPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    fieldPane.add(hourField);
    fieldPane.add(dayField);
    fieldPane.add(monthField);
    fieldPane.add(yearField);
    fieldPane.add(timeAdded);

    JPanel newTimePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    newTimePanel.add(newTime);

    JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    labels.add(hourLabel);
    labels.add(dayLabel);
    labels.add(monthLabel);
    labels.add(yearLabel);
    labels.add(timeAdded1);

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    add(fieldPane, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    add(labels, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
}


private static void createAndShowGUI()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Clock Adder");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.add(new displayFrame());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            hrsIn = Integer.parseInt(hourField.getText());
            daysIn = Integer.parseInt(dayField.getText());
            monthsIn = Integer.parseInt(monthField.getText());
            yearsIn = Integer.parseInt(yearField.getText());
            timeAdd = Integer.parseInt(timeAdded.getText());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, basic.output);
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            createAndShowGUI();
            }
        }
    );
}   
}
```

Calculating class code:

```
package clock;

public class basic {

    static int year = displayFrame.yearsIn;
    static int month = displayFrame.monthsIn;
    static int day = displayFrame.daysIn;
    static int hour = displayFrame.hrsIn;

    public static String output;

    double yearD = year;
    double leapYear = yearD/4;
    int daysInMonth = 0;
    int daysInYear = 365;
    int casePick = 0;
    int hoursAdded = 0;
    int x = 0;{

    //Making sure that the number added isn't negative, ones for other inputs MAY come...
    while(x == 0)
    {
    if(Math.abs(hoursAdded) != hoursAdded){
        continue;
    }else{
        x++;
    }

    /*Starts the counting loop and for each month value, it will determine how many days are in it
    this will allow for exact measurement.*/
    while(hoursAdded > 0){
        switch(month)
        {
        case 1:
            daysInMonth = 31;
            break;
        case 2:
            if(leapYear % 1 == 0){
            daysInYear = 366;
            daysInMonth = 29;
        }else{
            daysInMonth = 28;
        }
        break;
        case 3:
            daysInMonth = 31;
            break;
        case 4:
            daysInMonth = 30;
            break;
        case 5:
            daysInMonth = 31;
            break;
        case 6:
            daysInMonth = 30;
            break;
        case 7:
            daysInMonth = 31;
            break;
        case 8:
            daysInMonth = 31;
            break;
        case 9:
            daysInMonth = 30;
            break;
        case 10:
            daysInMonth = 31;
            break;
        case 11:
            daysInMonth = 30;
            break;
        case 12:
            daysInMonth = 31;
            break;
        }


        /*Decides whether a year, month, day or hour is left, adds one to its counter,
          and then takes away that amount of time from the hours added that are left*/
        if(hoursAdded >= daysInYear * 24){
            hoursAdded = hoursAdded - (daysInYear * 24);
            year++;
            break;
        }

        if(hoursAdded >= daysInMonth * 24 && hoursAdded < daysInYear * 24){
            hoursAdded =  hoursAdded - (daysInMonth * 24);
            month++;
            break;
        }

        if(hoursAdded >= 24 && hoursAdded < daysInMonth * 24){
            hoursAdded = hoursAdded - 24;
            day++;
            break;
        }

        if(hoursAdded >= 1 && hoursAdded < 24){
            hoursAdded = hoursAdded - 1;
            hour++;
            break;
        }   

    //Makes sure there are never 25 hours, 32 days or 13 months
    if(hour > 24){
        day++;
        hour = 1;
    }

    if(day > daysInMonth){
        month++;
        day = 1;
    }

    if(month > 12){
        year++;
        month = 1;
    }
}   
        output = "hello";
        /*hello is a test value, this will be the actual value: 
        ("The date you have requested is: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " Hour:" + hour);*/
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You to get the value you want to display (I assume from `basic`) and pass it to (I assume `displayFrame`). `static` is NOT a inter class communication mechanism and should NOT be used as such.  It's two easy for multiple instance of a class to change the values unexpected and you end up with no end of problems. You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: Mind you, I'm not even sure you `basic` class will compile...You might find it easier to use Java 8's `Time` API or JodaTime to make calculations with date/times...

Comment: basic does work and it does compile, all I did was remove the main method. I call the class to do some math when needed. I did think about using an API but decided it would teach me more to do it this way. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: Really, because that `while-loop` can exist outside of a method context?

Comment: I get no errors or anything thought my program

Comment: Oh, I see, you've put it inside a initialisation block...brilliant...

Comment: Yeah, all good, you know how to fix the whole won't display thing?

Comment: Yeah actually it doesn't work, it compiles but won't give an output, re-added the main method in the correct place, still doesnt even println..

Comment: It has worked with that code in the past, however. Before the whole JFrame thing. And yes I did set the values to a number instead of getting them from another class

Comment: Make you calculation "stuff" into a method which can be called, passing the required informaiton to and return the `String` result...

Comment: Can you enlighten me on what it is you are actually trying to achieve....it "seems" you are trying to calculate the time difference, but is' hard to tell...

Comment: I hope something helped

Comment: Any idea how to put the values from when I press the button from my display class to my basic class, I can't put a method inside a method. I am trying to make a program that takes the time entered and adds a user-given number of hours to it. Displays in mm/dd/yyyy, hour:hh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method which takes your parameters and returns your result...

```
enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        hrsIn = Integer.parseInt(hourField.getText());
        daysIn = Integer.parseInt(dayField.getText());
        monthsIn = Integer.parseInt(monthField.getText());
        yearsIn = Integer.parseInt(yearField.getText());
        timeAdd = Integer.parseInt(timeAdded.getText());

        String result = Basic.addTimeTo(yearsIn, monthsIn, daysIn, hrsIn, timeAdd);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, result);
    }
});
```

Restructure your `Basic` class to take parameters into a method and return the required value...

```
public class Basic {

    public static String addTimeTo(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int timeToAdd) {
        // Perform calculations...
        // return result...
    }

//  static int year = displayFrame.yearsIn;
//  static int month = displayFrame.monthsIn;
//  static int day = displayFrame.daysIn;
//  static int hour = displayFrame.hrsIn;
//
//  public static String output;
//
//  double yearD = year;
//  double leapYear = yearD / 4;
//  int daysInMonth = 0;
//  int daysInYear = 365;
//  int casePick = 0;
//  int hoursAdded = 0;
//  int x = 0;
//
//  {
//
//      //Making sure that the number added isn't negative, ones for other inputs MAY come...
//      while (x == 0) {
//          if (Math.abs(hoursAdded) != hoursAdded) {
//              continue;
//          } else {
//              x++;
//          }
//
//          /*Starts the counting loop and for each month value, it will determine how many days are in it
//           this will allow for exact measurement.*/
//          while (hoursAdded > 0) {
//              switch (month) {
//                  case 1:
//                      daysInMonth = 31;
//                      break;
//                  case 2:
//                      if (leapYear % 1 == 0) {
//                          daysInYear = 366;
//                          daysInMonth = 29;
//                      } else {
//                          daysInMonth = 28;
//                      }
//                      break;
//                  case 3:
//                      daysInMonth = 31;
//                      break;
//                  case 4:
//                      daysInMonth = 30;
//                      break;
//                  case 5:
//                      daysInMonth = 31;
//                      break;
//                  case 6:
//                      daysInMonth = 30;
//                      break;
//                  case 7:
//                      daysInMonth = 31;
//                      break;
//                  case 8:
//                      daysInMonth = 31;
//                      break;
//                  case 9:
//                      daysInMonth = 30;
//                      break;
//                  case 10:
//                      daysInMonth = 31;
//                      break;
//                  case 11:
//                      daysInMonth = 30;
//                      break;
//                  case 12:
//                      daysInMonth = 31;
//                      break;
//              }
//
//
//              /*Decides whether a year, month, day or hour is left, adds one to its counter,
//               and then takes away that amount of time from the hours added that are left*/
//              if (hoursAdded >= daysInYear * 24) {
//                  hoursAdded = hoursAdded - (daysInYear * 24);
//                  year++;
//                  break;
//              }
//
//              if (hoursAdded >= daysInMonth * 24 && hoursAdded < daysInYear * 24) {
//                  hoursAdded = hoursAdded - (daysInMonth * 24);
//                  month++;
//                  break;
//              }
//
//              if (hoursAdded >= 24 && hoursAdded < daysInMonth * 24) {
//                  hoursAdded = hoursAdded - 24;
//                  day++;
//                  break;
//              }
//
//              if (hoursAdded >= 1 && hoursAdded < 24) {
//                  hoursAdded = hoursAdded - 1;
//                  hour++;
//                  break;
//              }
//
//              //Makes sure there are never 25 hours, 32 days or 13 months
//              if (hour > 24) {
//                  day++;
//                  hour = 1;
//              }
//
//              if (day > daysInMonth) {
//                  month++;
//                  day = 1;
//              }
//
//              if (month > 12) {
//                  year++;
//                  month = 1;
//              }
//          }
//          output = "hello";
//          /*hello is a test value, this will be the actual value: 
//           ("The date you have requested is: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " Hour:" + hour);*/
//      }
//  }
}
```

You `Basic` class and `addTimeTo` should be completely decoupled from all other classes and information and be completely reliant on what it is passed (with the exception to information it needs to perform it's internal calculations, like `daysInYear` for example)

Unless otherwise required, I would also encourage you to make use of Java 8's `Time` API or JodaTime to perform your calculations

Comment: So what would the String result be for? Just to write the values to the basic values (Thanks for all your help by the way.)

Comment: After you've made your calculations, you need to send the result back to the caller, so the caller can do something with it...

Comment: Wonderful, all the stuff is going through, looking like some of my old calculations are wrong, great, thanks for all the help with the display stuff though!

Comment: Yeah if you could see of any reason why my while loop is only running once that would be great too!